# How do I export items from Blender to Tinkercad

Tags: export

Is there a way I can create a design in blender and then open it in tinkercad. I am doing this for a school class and this will help get me into college.

Comment: **Step #1:** Investigate what formats Tinker CAD can import **Step #2:** See what formats Blender can export **Step #3:** Find a match between the two **Step #4:** Profit

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, you can. But first you have to decide what format you want your design to be in. But it will export both 3D objects (which I believe TinkerCAD does accept) and .svg files, which, as far as I know, are intended for curve/vector data.